# How to work with multiple ruby on rails applications on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to run two rails apps which have rails version 3.1.10, 4.0.2 & ruby 1.9.2, 2.1.0. Is it possible to do this using Heroku?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you specify the ruby and rails version in your Gemfiles, heroku will take care of it for you. I have an app running on ruby 1.9.2 and rails 3.2.13 and another on ruby 2.0.0 and rails 4.0.3.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible just make sure that the ruby versions with rails 4. It requires Ruby version 2.0.0+. 
Just check the 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails3
for the pre requisites.